# How to check if Console.Out was set using my TextWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm changing the Console out to a custom TextWriterclass (TextBoxStreamWriter). I want to check if the Console.Out was set using my writer instance or not (because other class may have changed it, etc).

Sample:

```
// "TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter" is a custom class that writes to a textbox...
TextBoxStreamWriter myWriter = new TextBoxStreamWriter(someTextBoxInstance);
Console.SetOut(myWriter);
bool check = Console.Out == myWriter;
// But check is false! I need to know if .Out was set from my custom class or not.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.SetOut` will wrap your `myWriter` in a another `TextWriter` to make it thread safe by wrapping all the calls in a `lock`. This is the reason why you get false when you check `Console.Out == myWriter;`

You need some reflection code to check it, because the wrapping TextWriter is internal. It is named as `SyncTextWriter`.

You can refer the [source here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,2d6029756ecc3409) for more information.

Comment: As a workaround I'm holding the Out reference just after setting it, so I can check it later. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's expected, look at the `Console.SetOut` source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,2d6029756ecc3409 . It wraps your text writer in a `SyncTextWriter`.

I think you have to use reflection to see the wrapped type.